# Wildcard filter in power query gives 0 output

Tags: excel, dax, powerquery, m

My question is the extension of my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73931477/countifs-sumifs-in-excel-power-query-gives-wrong-output-for-large-dataset) question.
The previous question was related to countifs and sumifs in powerquery, in this there is static search where product "P1" is searched, but P1 contains more values.
For example P1xxxxxx.

Below is the updated screenshot of my table.

[image]

Below is the code which was answered in [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73931477/countifs-sumifs-in-excel-power-query-gives-wrong-output-for-large-dataset) question

```
    let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"shop", type text}, {"shelf", type text}, {"product", type text}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"shop"}, {
    {"data", each Table.AddColumn(_, "countifs", each if [product]="p1" then 1 else 0), type table },
    {"sumifs", each Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(_, each [product] = "p1")),type number   }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"shelf", "product", "countifs"}, {"shelf", "product", "countifs"})
in #"Expanded data"
```

In above code p1 is searched static, but I tried to add *p1* show that while filter it can take values before and after p1.

Below is the code which I tried.

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"shop", type text}, {"shelf", type text}, {"product", type text}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"shop"}, {
    {"data", each Table.AddColumn(_, "countifs", each if [product]="*p1*" then 1 else 0), type table },
    {"sumifs", each Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(_, each [product] = "*p1*")),type number   }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"shelf", "product", "countifs"}, {"shelf", "product", "countifs"})
in #"Expanded data"
```

the above code gives output as 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asterisk (*) is not a wildcard in M.  Try Text.StartsWith([product], "p1")

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"shop", type text}, {"shelf", type text}, {"product", type text}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"shop"}, {
    {"data", each Table.AddColumn(_, "countifs", each if Text.StartsWith([product], "p1") then 1 else 0), type table },
    {"sumifs", each Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(_, each Text.StartsWith([product], "p1"))),type number   }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"shelf", "product", "countifs"}, {"shelf", "product", "countifs"})
in #"Expanded data"
```

sample data:

| shop | shelf | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | a1 | p123213 |
| a | a2 | p212323 |
| a | a3 | p113412 |
| a | a4 | p14343 |
| b | b1 | p251234 |
| b | b2 | p2r5324 |
| b | b3 | p1e3434 |
| c | c1 | p1r43 |
| c | c2 | p134 |
| c | c3 | p4werwer |
| c | c4 | p32343 |
| c | c5 | p1234 |

Comment: gives error : formula firewall: Query Table1 (step ‘Added Custom’) reference other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please rebuild this data combination.

Comment: I don't even use a step named Added Custom in my code, so that error can't be coming from my code.  The code above works with the sample data above.  If you are adapting it, check what step names feed into other step name. You have not provided enough data for us to figure out that part

Comment: @ron needs to configure his privacy levels, or rework the query. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/desktop-privacy-levels and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/set-privacy-levels-power-query-cc3ede4d-359e-4b28-bc72-9bee7900b540

Comment: formula worked fine.